# Ion-select UI for checkbox

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m stuck on a quick change of the ion-select component.
I’m trying to keep a persistent way to display the alert, but checkbox are for sure doing what they want.

To explain, I need to put the checkbox on the right side of the alert. After investigations, I notice that on Android, it’s on the left by default, but in iOS, for a simple ion-select, squares are on the right, and when I use “multiple” property on ion-select, squares are going to be align on the left.

Does anybody knows how it’s possible to put these checkbox on right on all cases ?

N.B: There’s also something weird in iOS, when it’s an simple ion-select, it displays simple check without any circle. (Compares to multiple, that have circles with check on the left.)

Also, sorry for my english, improving it.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ionic 4/5, try using display:flex (Check this out for the details: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Plus, the css for popup component(alert,toast,loader, etc) wont work if you do it on the page.css file, thus I recommend to overwrite the CSS on the global.css file.